# Send an email notification from a script

Tags: windows, email, scripting

What is the easiest way from a Windows server to send an email notification?

I need simple program or script to email a user for 2 different scripts I need to create. I do not have a scripting language preference.

One script will needs to send an email notification when their password is about to expire. The other script needs to email a user the password for a generic account on weekly basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) and [this example](http://www.blat.net/examples/batch.html) on how to run it from a batch file. Also nice is that it's a standalone utility that doesn't require installation.

Comment: Ya' know, I was going to mention blat but decided I'd get laughed at for not using some fancy PowerShell-based thing. I love blat, and use it frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an email server on your network that this server can reach

[TechNet Script Center Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a0e7a8ab-0311-4882-bd39-1638e34e4026)

Just replace "smarthost" with the name of the email server